# Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object extends NativeWrapper - Library:'dart:ui' Class: Path)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

Can anyone tell me whats wrong in this code?

```
void onPressed() async {
    //Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/screen2", arguments: []);
    var receivePort = ReceivePort();
    await Isolate.spawn(gotoNext, [receivePort.sendPort]);
    final msg = await receivePort.first;
    print(msg);
  }

  void gotoNext(List<dynamic> args) {
    SendPort sendPort = args[0];
    log(args.toString());
    Isolate.exit(sendPort, "OK");
  }
```

> E/flutter (12062): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object extends NativeWrapper - Library:'dart:ui' Class: Path)

Comment: [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/samples/blob/master/isolates/bin/send_and_receive.dart) the official doc which I have followed. They are saying we can only pass primitive data type but I am getting Error with the similar code.

Comment: Even this code also generating the same problem. `void onPressed() async {  
      await Isolate.spawn(gotoNext, "OK");
    }  

    void gotoNext(String args) {
      log(args);
    }`

Comment: where are you sending `Path` object?

Comment: I am not sending bro. Thats why I am also unable to track the root cause of the problem. I have simply calling the **onPressed** Function on a TextButton Tap.

Comment: >E/flutter (12519): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: (object extends NativeWrapper - Library:'dart:ui' Class: Path)
E/flutter (12519): #0      Isolate._spawnFunction (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:395:25)
E/flutter (12519): #1      Isolate.spawn (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:375:7)
E/flutter (12519): #2      _Screen1State.onPressed (package:practice/screen_1.dart:32:19)
E/flutter (12519): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)

Comment: i used that code: `void onPressed() async {
var receivePort = ReceivePort();
await Isolate.spawn(gotoNext, [receivePort.sendPort]);
final msg = await receivePort.first;
print('received >$msg<');
}

void gotoNext(List<dynamic> args) {
SendPort sendPort = args[0];
print('>input parameters: $args<');
Isolate.exit(sendPort, "OK");
}` and this is what i see on the logs after calling `onPressed` function: `[+5088 ms] flutter: >input parameters: [SendPort]<
[  +12 ms] flutter: received >OK<`

Comment: Can you please let me know your flutter and dart version. cos I am using latest one.

Comment: `Flutter 2.11.0-0.1.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b101bfe32f (3 weeks ago) • 2022-02-16 07:36:54 -0800
Engine • revision e355993572
Tools • Dart 2.17.0 (build 2.17.0-69.2.beta) • DevTools 2.10.0-dev.1`

Comment: Actually it is not running inside any Widget class. can you guide me how I can achieve this now ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hii There is a mistake in your code.  As far as I know from the official documentation The callback method for an Isolate should be a **top level function** or a `static` method.
**So there are two solution for this problem.**

> Solution 1. declare callback function as top level function.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: TextButton(
        child: const Text("Run Isolate"),
        onPressed: _onPressed,
      ));
    );
  }

  // Callback function for Text Button Event this should be a class member
  void _onPressed() async {
    var receivePort = ReceivePort();
    // Here runMyIsolate methos should be a top level function
    await Isolate.spawn(runMyIsolate, [receivePort.sendPort, "My Custom Message"]);
    print(await receivePort.first);
  }
}


// We declare a top level function here for an isolated callback function
void runMyIsolate(List<dynamic> args) {
  var sendPort = args[0] as SendPort;
  print("In runMyIsolate ");
  Isolate.exit(sendPort, args);
}
```

> Solution 2. instead this top level function we can declare this
> function as a `static` function for the same class, consider below
> example.

```
    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: TextButton(
        child: const Text("Run Isolate"),
        onPressed: _onPressed,
      ));
    );
  }

  // Callback function for Text Button Event this should be a class member
  void _onPressed() async {
    var receivePort = ReceivePort();
    // Here runMyIsolate methos should be a top level function
    await Isolate.spawn(runMyIsolate, [receivePort.sendPort, "My Custom Message"]);
    print(await receivePort.first);
  }
  
  // We declare a static function here for an isolated callback function
  static void runMyIsolate(List<dynamic> args) {
    var sendPort = args[0] as SendPort;
    print("In runMyIsolate ");
    Isolate.exit(sendPort, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes Now it is working for me Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue today. Turns out the code was not supposed to run inside a widget class, the examples use them outside. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Exactly you are right! It is working in main thread but not from a Widget class.
`void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
  var receivePort = ReceivePort();
  await Isolate.spawn(gotoNext, [receivePort.sendPort]);
  final msg = await receivePort.first;
  print('received >$msg<');
}

void gotoNext(List<dynamic> args) {
  SendPort sendPort = args[0];
  print('>input parameters: $args<');
  Isolate.exit(sendPort, "OK");
}`

Answer (score 0):

arg is List<dynamic> not List<SendPort> so code is not valid

```
SendPort sendPort = args[0];
```

please try, if arg[0] is SendPort:

```
void _readAndParseJson(List<dynamic> args) async {
  SendPort? responsePort;
  final dynamic _responsePort = args[0];

  if (_responsePort != null && _responsePort is SendPort) {
    responsePort = _responsePort;
  }
  String? fileName;
  final dynamic _fileName = args[1];
  if (_fileName != null && _fileName is String) {
    fileName = _fileName;
  }
  final fileData = await File(fileName).readAsString();
  final result = jsonDecode(fileData) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  Isolate.exit(responsePort, result);
}
```

Comment: But List<SendPort> will not be the primitive type? Also I have tried to Pass Map, String and int value but problem was remains.

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/samples/blob/master/isolates/bin/send_and_receive.dart) documentation provided here.

Comment: pls try: 
```
SendPort sendPort = args[0] as SendPort;
```

Comment: This was an Unnecessary cast bro. Also Not working.

Comment: @VarunVerma see my edit

Comment: @VarunVerma add "final result = jsonDecode(fileData) as Map<String, dynamic>;"

Comment: Nothing is helping bro.. feeling hopeless now.

Comment: Is  this example working for you ?

Comment: maybe you used jsonDecode and Isolate.exit wrong way

Comment: i don't know what you want to do, in this case i wouldn't use "result" like that

Answer (score 0):

In my case, The reason is because I passed argument Object too complicated to heavy task.

```
 final isolate = await Isolate.spawn<List<dynamic>>(
    getIncidentListIsolate,
    [receivePort.sendPort, _affairService]);
```

`_affairService` is one complicated object.
I replace with String, it it works fine.